# How deep does a 0.5mm radius drill need to drill before it start to hurt the brain assuming the drill bit will be pull off without wiggle?

Tags: human-anatomy

How deep does a 0.5mm radius drill into the brain need to drill before it start to hurt the brain permanently assuming the drill bit will be pull off without wiggle?

I am assessing how fragile of a brain is.

What are three types of damage that are most likely to happen for 3mm deep, 6mm deep or even deeper

Comment: Don't you have a drill? Just test on yourself!

Comment: @mdperry I want to do this but not after you show me how much the damage is :)

Comment: I think we need more information. Are you drilling through the bone first, because that's where the pain receptors will be. The brain itself, not so much.

Comment: @kmm It is the brain as I want to know how sophisticated a brain surgeries need to be conduct as i wanting to be a brain surgeon in the future